# Putty formatting

Tags: putty, bash-scripting, awk

When I run the following one-liner, I get run-on output in PuTTY like so: 
  (`\` added below to make it easier to read, which is not included in the actual one-liner script)
[image: Screesnhot1]

```
fileName=10M.csv ; \
for k in {1..3}; do for i in {1..1}; do for j in {blue,red,yellow}; do \ 

working=`cat "$fileName" | \
awk -v i=$i -v j=$j -v k=$k -F',' '{ if ( $1 == j && $2 == i && $3 == k ) print $1","$2","$3","$4","$13","$14}'`; \
nJ=${j:0:1}; \
nJ=${nJ^^}; \
echo "$i $j $nJ $k"; \
new="$i""_""$nJ""_""$k""_.txt"; \
echo $new; \
echo $working; \

done; done; done
```

However, I get nice output if I simplify the script by removing the `working=` part of line 3 [not counting blank lines] and corresponding "ticks", such that `cat` executes as expected; it isn't until it is encased in the `working` variable that the CSV table become run-on when `echo`-ed:
[image: Screenshot2]

```
fileName=10M.csv ; \
for k in {1..3}; do for i in {1..1}; do for j in {blue,red,yellow}; do \ 

cat "$fileName" | \
awk -v i=$i -v j=$j -v k=$k -F',' '{ if ( $1 == j && $2 == i && $3 == k ) print $1","$2","$3","$4","$13","$14}'; \
nJ=${j:0:1}; \
nJ=${nJ^^}; \
echo "$i $j $nJ $k"; \
new="$i""_""$nJ""_""$k""_.txt"; \
echo $new; \

done; done; done
```

What is going wrong with my script to produce the run-on output in PuTTY?

- I am guessing it has to do with `awk`, but I am minimally skilled in AWK, and tried to piece-mail the proper `awk` syntax when working with CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to double-quote `$working` when it is expanded (i.e. in your `echo` command), therefore it's subject to word splitting; instead of the entire value being a single argument to 'echo', each whitespace-separated word becomes a separate argument, with the original separators being lost since `echo` always joins the received arguments using a single space:

```
$ myvar="One Two
Three
Four Five"

$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' "$myvar"
["One Two\nThree\nFour Five"]

$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' $myvar
["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
```

- In general, the same would also apply to `` `cmd` ``, as well as `$(cmd)` and all other expansions, but your backtick usage happens to be exempt because it's part of a variable assignment – i.e. the specific case of `` var=`cmd` `` can technically be left unquoted, but changing it to `` var="`cmd`" ``, or even `var="$(cmd)"`, would not hurt and might improve understanding.

Comment: Thank you for catching my sloppiness. It is much appreciated.